# Worksheet limit in Excel 2003 (BIFF8)

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2003

Is there a limit in the number of worksheets ("tabs") allowed by the Excel 2003 format (aka BIFF8)?

I can find plenty of information about rows and columns but not worksheets.

Comment: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Excel-specifications-and-limits-1672b34d-7043-467e-8e27-269d656771c3

Comment: @ScottCraner From your link: *Applies To: Excel 2016 Excel 2013 Excel 2010 Excel 2007*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not a harcoded limit.

The limit is related to the memory available in the system.

Comment: Thank you. I guess that asking for an official Microsoft link for version 2003 that hasn't been taken off-line would be too much... <:-)

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález This is the best that I can get [Excel 2003 How-to](http://www.sql.com.my/document/Excel_2003_Specifications_&_Limits.pdf)